# Display date picker below input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker when I click on input field calendar display above the input field. I want to display it bellow input field.

**JS**

```
$(function () {
        $("#fFYear").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            autoclose: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            //gotoCurrent: true,
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
        //alert("#FirstFiscalTo");

    });
```

**Input Field**

```
<input class="textboxCO input-sm form-control datePickerPickcer" id="fiscalYear" name="FiscalYear" type="text" value="6/30/2015 7:12:21 AM">
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or you can try by using `position:relative` css for parent element of datepicker.

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#orientation is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Look at my answer on <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/46175560/7250028">link</a>. You will get correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
        $("#fiscalYear").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            autoclose: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            //gotoCurrent: true,
        });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="fiscalYear" name="FiscalYear" type="text" value="6/30/2015 7:12:21 AM">
```

Comment: What specifically in this snippet fixes the problem?

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 18):

Lücks solution is the one, just one minor detail `dateFormat` option is not valid, is `format` as referenced in the official doc [here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/stable/options.html#format). You are not noticing this error because `"mm/dd/yy"` is the default format.

So, te solution will look like:

```
$(function () {
    $("#fiscalYear").datepicker({ //<-- yea .. the id was not right
        format: "mm/dd/yy", // <-- format, not dateFormat
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        autoclose: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        //gotoCurrent: true,
       orientation: "top" // <-- and add this
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$(function () {
        $("#fiscalYear").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            autoclose: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            //gotoCurrent: true,
           orientation: "top" // add this
        });
});
```

Reference: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#orientation

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#fFYear").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    autoclose: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    orientation: "bottom left" // left bottom of the input field
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for..Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

For datepicker from jquery rather than bootstrap, option [orientation] is not available.
The positioning of the datepicker panel is auto set by jquery depending on the cursor position relative to the window.

To ensure that datepicker is always below the cursor position when an input field is selected, I used the below code

```
$("input").datepicker().click(function(e){
  $('.ui-datepicker').css('top', e.pageY);
})
```

e.pageY is the current mouse Y axis position in window.
as class ui-datepicker position is absolute, when "top" attribute is set to cursor Y axis value, the datepicker ui panel will be displayed always below cursor.